# Wrap Rx JS Observable by chaining

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

Is there a way to map an Observerable into another by chaining? I'm currently doing this:

```
const myObserverable = fnThatReturnsObserverable();
return anotherFunctionThatReturnsObserverable(myObserverable);
```

Is there a way to do this in a chained manner?

```
return fnThatReturnsObserverable().someOperator(anotherFunctionThatReturnsObserverable)
```

Comment: are you wanting to chain observ_ers_ or observ_ables_?

Comment: @Brandom, Observables, I'll update my question.

Comment: @MarcelM. I think `let()` is what you're looking for, although it's undocimented https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operator/let.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fnThatReturnsObserverable()
    .let(obs => anotherFunctionThatReturnsObserverable(obs));
```

More information on it [here](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/let.md).

Answer (score -1):

You can also use `of` and `mergeMap(or concatMap)`

```
Observable.of(fnThatReturnsObserverable())
    .mergeMap(ob => anotherFunctionThatReturnsObserverable(obs));
```

Comment: This is just illogical

Comment: @RobinDijkhof What logic do you mean?

Comment: Creating a observable of a observable just so can use mergeMap while the operator let exists.

Comment: Okay, I understand. But I think it not a matter of 'logic'. `let` is relatively less known. So I have also introduced other ways to use familiar operators.